# Installation of xamarin in windows 7 failed

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to install xamarin on my system, But got the below error:

My System details:
OS - Windows 7 (64 bit)
Visual Studio - 2015 community edition

> Installation of 'Intel® HAXM' failed with more than one exception (attempt 3)
>   Errors while installing items.
>   Exception type: System.AggregateException
>   Installation of software item 'Intel® HAXM' failed with exception.
>   Exception type: Xamarin.Web.Installer.InstallException
>   Full stack trace:
>   at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.InstallDownloadedItem(String url, InstallationArchiveHandler handler, DownloadServiceWorkItem download)
>   at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.Install(UInt32 tryNumber)
>   at WindowsInstaller.ProgressPage.InstallationWorker()
>   Installation of software item 'Intel® HAXM' failed with exception.
>   Exception type: Xamarin.Web.Installer.InstallException
>   Full stack trace:
>   at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.InstallDownloadedItem(String url, InstallationArchiveHandler handler, DownloadServiceWorkItem download)
>   at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.Install(UInt32 tryNumber)
>   at WindowsInstaller.ProgressPage.InstallationWorker()
>   Installation of software item 'Intel® HAXM' failed with exception.
>   Exception type: Xamarin.Web.Installer.InstallException
>   Full stack trace:
>   at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.InstallDownloadedItem(String url, InstallationArchiveHandler handler, DownloadServiceWorkItem download)
>   at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.Install(UInt32 tryNumber)
>   at WindowsInstaller.ProgressPage.InstallationWorker()

Installation of 'Intel® HAXM' failed with more than one exception (attempt 3)
Errors while installing items.
Exception type: System.AggregateException
Installation of software item 'Intel® HAXM' failed with exception.
Exception type: Xamarin.Web.Installer.InstallException
Full stack trace:
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.InstallDownloadedItem(String url, InstallationArchiveHandler handler, DownloadServiceWorkItem download)
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.Install(UInt32 tryNumber)
at WindowsInstaller.ProgressPage.InstallationWorker()
Installation of software item 'Intel® HAXM' failed with exception.
Exception type: Xamarin.Web.Installer.InstallException
Full stack trace:
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.InstallDownloadedItem(String url, InstallationArchiveHandler handler, DownloadServiceWorkItem download)
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.Install(UInt32 tryNumber)
at WindowsInstaller.ProgressPage.InstallationWorker()
Installation of software item 'Intel® HAXM' failed with exception.
Exception type: Xamarin.Web.Installer.InstallException
Full stack trace:
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.InstallDownloadedItem(String url, InstallationArchiveHandler handler, DownloadServiceWorkItem download)
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.Install(UInt32 tryNumber)
at WindowsInstaller.ProgressPage.InstallationWorker()

[image]

EDIT: Thank you Lex.
I am getting below error while installing HAXM from the link given by Lex.
[image]

EDIT: I ran the HAV Detection tool and below is the output. I think my system does not support Hardware Assisted Virtualization and hence installation failed. How to resolve this issue ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can download and install HAXM from Intel directly,

https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

and then re-run the Xamarin installer for the rest.